# Javascript pretty url regular expresison

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create regular expression for specific url router, for detail item. Here is written unit test, for expression.

https://regex101.com/r/LUo5k9/2/tests

For explonation, I need this:

http://localhost:8080/ -> home

http://localhost:8080/specific-detail-item -> detail

My current using expression is: `/\/[^/]+(.+)/`

For detail expression accept, but for home is too. It shouldn't.

How can I solve it?

Comment: does it need to match only those two?

Comment: So, with regular expression probably yes. Others are routes in string, something like: "/about", "/list" ... Regexp should by accept only pattern host/some-url-id

Comment: You know you can click `<>` and post examples here?

Comment: Yes, but why? A Unit test should suffice.

Comment: Because links go stale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require the `/` explicitly as the first character in the capture group, otherwise `[^/]+` can match fewer characters than you expect:

[`\/[^/]+(\/.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LUo5k9/3)

Comment: Thank you for answer, update looks well. And is possible get group 1, without  '/' ? For example: test-xxx, without /text-xxx.? I can simple remove with javascript, if it is problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just move the `\/` before the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for help.